# JSON iterate over JArray and Add property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm starting with this JSON:

```
{
    "name": "company",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "WorkStatus",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "DeploymentCode",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "entity",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastUpdatedDate",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastUpdatedBy",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "EffectiveDate",
        "type": "string"
    }]
}
```

I want to add (default) to each of the fields so I end up with this:

```
{
    "name": "company",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "WorkStatus",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    },
    {
        "name": "DeploymentCode",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    },
    {
        "name": "entity",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastUpdatedDate",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    },
    {
        "name": "lastUpdatedBy",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    },
    {
        "name": "EffectiveDate",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "null"
    }]
}
```

I have this code so far but I blow up on the Add:

```
JObject entireSchema = JObject.Parse(jsonResult.ToString());
JArray fieldsArray = (JArray)entireSchema["fields"];

foreach (var field in fieldsArray)
                {
                    field.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("default", "null"));

                }
```

I know this be something small but I don't have a complete grasp of all the JObject and JArray functions.
What am I missing to get this added to each of the fields?

Comment: You should look through array item properties to add a `default` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string jsonString = "{'name':'company','type':'record','fields':[{'name':'WorkStatus','type':'string'},{'name':'DeploymentCode','type':'string'},{'name':'entity','type':'string'},{'name':'lastUpdatedDate','type':'string'},{'name':'lastUpdatedBy','type':'string'},{'name':'EffectiveDate','type':'string'}]}";
        //Note: You must convert to JObject

        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString); 

        var jsonFields = jsonObject["fields"]; 
        List<JObject> jsonList = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var item in jsonFields)
        {
            var tempJson = JObject.Parse(item.ToString());
            tempJson.Add("default", "null");
            jsonList.Add(tempJson);
        }
        var getListJson = JToken.FromObject(jsonList);
        //Fixed! :)
        jsonObject.Remove("fields");
        jsonObject.Add("fields", getListJson);
```

that's it!